# How to make background image span the entire width of the page using css in Squarespace

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm trying to add custom css to a Squarespace page that will add a background image behind a block of text to this page: https://www.seacureadvisors.com/seacure-advisors.

The code I have added to the page is:

```css
div#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1710885486557_10443{
background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5fce63b9abf5bd69920abec0/t/5fdade0435c0500e7fa30a42/1608179207346/footer-bg.png);
 padding-top:40px;
 padding-bottom:40px;
    background-size: cover!important;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 13px; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom:-85px;
 margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1710885486557_10443"></div>
```

How would I get the image to span the entire width of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is in fact no way to add that content to its own section which is set to be full width (instead of it being a part of the main body), then the following CSS, added to the CSS you posted in your question, will achieve the full-width effect that you're looking for.

```
width: calc(100vw - 17px);
margin-left: calc((100vw - (100% + 17px)) / -2);
box-sizing: border-box;
```

As a preemptive note, if you were to add the CSS via the CSS Editor instead of via a `style` tag as you did, you would have to use the following instead of the above, due to Squarespace's LESS interpreter/compiler:

```
width: ~"calc(100vw - 17px)";
margin-left: ~"calc((100vw - (100% + 17px)) / -2)";
box-sizing: border-box;
```